# Album not eligible for iCloud Music Library. Why?

Tags: itunes, icloud

I have an album I bought the uncompressed version of (wav) and used iTunes to make an Apple Lossless version of. I've updated the song names, artist name, etc. I've met all the requirements: under 200MB, under 2 hours, bitrate ok (of course), and there is no DRM. But it still lists as ineligible. Why?

Here's the file summary.[image]

Edit: This was flagged as a possible duplicate. It's not. So here's my edit.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I've figured it out. iCloud Music Library supports up to 24bit@44.1KHz. The 96KHz is the problem

Comment: Just ran into the exact same issue and arrived at the same conclusion while I was searching for possible answers.  It's pretty widely known that your sample rate can't be too LOW, but this is the first place I've seen mention of it being too HIGH, which was also my problem.

Comment: Did you find documentation for this, or was this derived through trial and error?

I have an Apple Lossless (ALAC) file showing "ineligible" even though it's the same sample rate (44.1 KHz) as another ALAC file that Cloud Music Library accepts. Main difference I can see is the sample size (successful file is 24-bit; ineligible one is 16 bit), but up-sampling to 24-bit using ffmpeg didn't solve it.